# HTML Email 1px Border Gap Margin showing

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email, margin

I appear to be getting a 1px white box around my tables in outlook 2007,10 and 13. Ive done border collapse and it hasn't fixed the issue? Want three 200px tables aligned horizontally, but because a 1px border is being applied it thinks they're more than 200px, therefore breaking the alignment. Tried everything so any suggestions appreciated.

```html
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;border:none;padding:0px;margin:0px;" width="600" bgcolor="#B6B6B6" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr>
<td>


<table style="border-collapse: collapse;border:none;padding:0px;margin:0px;"  align="left" bgcolor="#EE070B" width="200" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr><td>1</td></tr>
</table>

<table style="border-collapse: collapse;border:none;padding:0px;margin:0px;"  align="left" bgcolor="#1527EA" width="200" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr><td>2</td></tr>
</table>

<table  style="border-collapse: collapse;border:none;padding:0px;margin:0px;" align="left" bgcolor="#ED7407" width="200" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
<tr><td>3</td></tr>
</table>

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: add border-size:0px in style

Comment: Sometimes email client have a strange behavior, if you can't remove the border change the color. Use the background color for border.
Is not a solution but sometimes is necessary a workaround.

Comment: @ShubhamNigam didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook adds around 20px around Tables, no matter what. Not sure on the 1px border but try this hack to fool all Outlook versions into thinking your Tables are Table cells: http://labs.actionrocket.co/make_mobile_email_work_in_outlook